# Sessions behind Firewall - NAT

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, session, firewall

I use [ionizecms](http://ionizecms.com/) for my little project. It uses codeigniter framework. The problem is:

- Application works when I enter local server IP like 192.168.x.x
- Application works when I enter from localhost from inside server
- Server uses apache and 192.168.x.x:xx port for http on Windows Server OS
- Server runs behind a firewall and it uses 212.xxx.xxx:xxxx ip with different port then redirects this ip:port to 192.168.x.x:xx

**Problem:** When you access page from 212.xxx.xxx:xxxx page loads once then if you refresh or login http request timeout. Sometimes it gives php timeout from a line session_start();

I don't know either this is a server side or application configuration problem. I googled it but there is no result.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is an application side problem, I have tested before similar conditions with IonizeCMS 1.x and if the ProxyPass right in Apache2 to redirect the network to an inside server then the codeigniter application working.

**The problem seems on the firewall redirection and *reverse redirection* method.** If the 192.168.x.x is working fine thats mean the inside server is good.

In apache a simple proxy redirection looks like this:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://192.168.x.x:80/
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.x.x:80/
```

I dont know what type of firewal do you use, so I could not send a perfect solution for that.